# jquery-timepicker en Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, time

Hola quiero agregar los cdm en el cakephp

[jquery-timepicker](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-timepicker)

pero no se como, los css si, y los js se que son con script pero el .map como lo llamaria en el default?

Bueno mi idea para usar el time-piker es que necesito insertar en una BD el inicio y final de una cita.
en la BD es solo un campo llamado cita de tipo varchar, y en el html estoy creando dos campos de tipo input para usar los time piker y lo que elijan en esos campos lo voy a guardar en un campo escondido, ese campo es el que se inserta con en la BD con el $this->.. create();

no se si tengan una alternativa mucho mas facil.

Comment: Los archivos `.map` son creados por los minificadores de código para tener una referencia y poder mostrarlos como estaban al principio, sí se necesita. Si lo quieres cargar lo harías con el HtmlHelper como un `css` normal `echo $this->Html->css('')`

Comment: Osea que no son necesarios, con el js y css tengo?

Comment: Correcto, puedes cargar los `min.css` y `min.js` o simplemente los `.css` y `js` y con eso te queda

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar esa librería lo que debes hacer es crear el input tipo texto con una clase en específico y añadirla en un script.

Obviamente tienes que tener insertado previamente el Jquery y la librería de timepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tuClase').timepicker({}) 
});
```